# Getting a CS7036 error when passing variables between methods for a calculator (from a code test I found on the internet))

Tags: c#, .net, methods, console, calculator

CS7036  C# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'num1' of 'Calculator.Add(int, int, int)' same error for subtracting, divide and multiply.

The test rules said that it must have separate methods for each operation.

Trying to get back into coding after taking an unavoidably long break. Thought tests would be a good way to spark the code brain again.

Anyway,

I've tried different method parameters, such as passing the variables as references and as straight values, different ways of calling the methods, different security parameters (private, public, static etc).

I've spent 2 hours trawling different forums and scripting references to see if there was anything, but so far no luck. The test rules said that it must have separate methods for each operation.

I had an earlier error about the num1 2 and op being passed without identifiers as well, so that may be contributing here.

I do know this isn't the most effective or efficient way to make a calculator, however, it is how the test wants it to be done.

```
using System;
        namespace code_challenge.Challenges
        {
        public class Calculator
        {

        /*
        * Within this Calculator class you will need to create 4 methods.
        * The four methods will relate to the basic functions of a calculator 
 and should be named:
        *
        *  - Add
        *  - Subtract
        *  - Multiply
        *  - Divide

        int num1 =0; int num2 =0; int ans =0; string op = " ";

        public void Input(int num1,int num2,int ans,string op)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first number.");
            num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the opperand.");
            op = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the Second number.");
            num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (op == "+")
            {
ERROR LINE   Add();
            }
            if (op == "-")
            {
ERROR LINE   Sub();
            }
            if (op == "*")
            {
ERROR LINE   Mul();
            }
            if (op == "/")
            {
ERROR LINE   Div();
            }
        }
        // Implement the add function below here
        public void Add(int num1, int num2, int ans)
        {
            ans = num1 + num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Your Answer is: " + ans);
        }
        // Implement the subtract function below here
        public void Sub(int num1,int num2,int  ans)
        {
            ans = num1 - num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Your Answer is: " + ans);
        }
        // Implement the multiply function below here
        public void Mul(int num1,int num2,int ans)
        {
            ans = num1 * num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Your Answer is: " + ans);
        }
        // Implement the divide function below here
        public void Div(int num1,int num2,int ans)
        {
            ans = num1 / num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Your Answer is: " + ans);
        }
    }
}
```

No actual output due to the errors.

The expected output is that the operand input will throw the if statement, which will throw the appropriate operation and push ans into the console

Comment: You've declared methods like `Add` to take parameters, but you're calling it without specifying any parameters. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll help you with Add op and you repeat this with other methods:
first,

```
if (op == "+")
{
   Add(num1, num2);
}
```

second, change add method

```
public void Add(int num1, int num2)
{
  ans = num1 + num2;
  Console.WriteLine($"Your Answer is: {num1 + num2}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are not passing any input arguments to the function. You should provide that.
Secondly, you do not need to have an input argument called `ans` in any of the function.
You can modify your function as following

```
public void Add(int num1,int num2){

    int ans = num1+num2;
    Console.WriteLine(ans);

}
```

Or you can return the value from the method for example:

```
public int Add(int num1,int num2){

    int ans = num1+num2;
    Console.WriteLine(ans);
    return ans;

}
```

and in the input method, pass
`Add(num1,num2)`